# Can you use Google Keyword Tool to find out key words that get searched?

Tags: search

Can you use Google Keyword Tool to find out key words that get searched?

I have looked into Google AdWord and Keyword Tool. All I could find was a way to pay a certain amount everyday for my website to be found easier when people googled certain keywords.

I simply want to see how often certain words are searched and in what areas.

Comment: Google adword provides in free what you want. You can check easily that how often certain keywords searches and volume.

Comment: Have you tried Google Trends??

Comment: @HelpingHands BTW- Google Keyword Tool is part of Adwords. In the past, anyone was able to use the tool without an account external to Adwords, but they changed that some time ago.

Comment: @closetnoc - I see , Actually I have used in free in past so...Thanks for update to me.

Comment: @closetnoc - can you please share link of google trends where I can search keywords? I tried but not getting exact page :(

Comment: @HelpingHands I used to use it when it was free so to speak, (still is but requires an account), but I do not use it anymore- though I guess I should. I use Google Trends the most.

Comment: @HelpingHands  http://www.google.com/trends/ Start a search, then add and delete terms and compare different terms or phrases. Be sure to look at the bottom of the page for trending terms including breakout. Take it with salt for a while and just poke around. Somewhere along the way, you will have an AH HA! moment and find a cluster of terms that are real winners. It is a way of looking into the mind of Google. As simple a tool as it is, it takes a little while before you get what works for your site.

Comment: @HelpingHands Anytime my friend!!

Answer (score 1):

Google trend is a great tool to visualize google data, you can analyze search terms by Interest over time, country and related queries.

https://trends.google.com

Answer (score 1):

You can analyse your competitors site with this site: https://www.semrush.com/

It will give you a summery of keywords that they use to rank etc.

You can also run an analysis on your own domain to get more info on your own site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Keyword Planner to get ranges of volume but it does not give very specific values anymore unless you spending money on Adwords.

Alternatively, you can setup a campaign (you don't need to activate it) and within the Ad settings there will be a screen where you can input some keywords and Google will show you related keywords with monthly volume associated.